# Generate a list of names/strings randomly of desired size in python and add it to a dataframe column

Tags: python, list

I am tying to generate a random list of names from a given set. I have tried two different ways (group_1) and group_2 below, but both times I am not able to generate a list of names as desired. While group_1 makes each character into a separate element of the lsit, group_2 just makes a single element list. while i need list of 342 elemetns.

code:

```
import random
first_names=('John','mary','hillary')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

group_1=list(" ".join(random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names) for _ in range(342)))
group_2 = [" ".join(random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names) for _ in range(342))]

print(group_1)
print(len(group_1))
print(group_2)
print(len(group_2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnecessary `" ".join` is what's causing this problem, you can just omit it (since you already have `+ " " +`) and use a list comprehension:

```
group = [random.choice(first_names) + " " + random.choice(last_names) for _ in range(342)]

print(len(group))
print(group)
```

Output:

```
342
['hillary Johnson', 'John Williams', 'John Johnson', 'mary Williams', 'mary Smith', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a list like the one shown below:

- hillary Smith
- mary Johnson
- John Johnson
- John Williams
- hillary Smith
- ......

This code will provide a list like that,

```
from random import randrange

first_names=('John','mary','hillary')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

names = [first_names[randrange(len(first_names))] + " " + last_names[randrange(len(last_names))] for _ in range(342)]
print (names)
```